# Javascript - querySelectorAll with a var

Tags: javascript

I have an SVG file with rome rects. On my index I have some options. If you click in one of them it changes the color of all the rects with a certain class.

SVG

```
<g class="Shape">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="60"/>
</g>
```

HTML

```
<a id="option1" onclick="filter('Shape')">Option 1</a>
```

JS

```
function filter(className){
   var rectColor = document.querySelectorAll('."className" rect');

   for (var i = 0; i < rectColor.length; i++) {
      rectColor[i].style.fill="#6E6F72";
   }
}
```

If I write the actual name on the querySelector (`document.querySelectorAll('.Shape rect')`) it works. I'm not sure how to do it with a variable. I'm getting "unexpected identifier" error.
 Thank you!

Comment: Just construct the selector string you want by adding multiple strings or string variables together: `"." + className + "rect"`

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP. If you want to include variables in your strings, you need to use string concatenation. (although that syntax wouldn't have worked in PHP either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the following

```
var rectColor = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className + ' rect');
```

As it is now, you're not actually passing your variable to querySelector, you're just calling it with the string literal `."className" rect`.